# Ip2location plugin in my template header?

Tags: templates, geo-data

I am using Ip2location plugin to pull state data based on Ip address into my post.

This is easy you install the plugin and then just use {ip:regionName} in the post or page editor.

But I want to print this information in my template header file right beside the title

is this possible and if so how do I go about this?

This is how the header php looks like in the template

```
        <?php

$def_header_text = esc_html__( 'This is Header Media Text.', 'cleanportfolio' );

if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
    $def_header_text .= '&nbsp;' . esc_html__( 'Edit this from Appearance - Customize - Header Media - Header Media Text.', 'cleanportfolio' );
}

$header_media_text = get_theme_mod( 'cleanportfolio_header_media_text', $def_header_text );

if ( is_front_page() && ( has_custom_header() || '' !== $header_media_text ) ) : ?>
    <div class="custom-header">
        <?php
        if ( has_custom_header() ) : ?>
            <div class="custom-header-media">
                <?php the_custom_header_markup(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="custom-header-content sections header-media-section">
        <?php if ( '' !== $header_media_text ) : ?>
            <h2 class="section-title"><?php echo esc_html( $header_media_text ); ?></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php if ( ! has_custom_header() ) : ?>
            <div class="square"><?php echo cleanportfolio_get_svg( array(
                'icon' => 'square',
            ) ); ?><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Square', 'cleanportfolio' ); ?></span></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- .custom-header -->
```

this is how ip2location says to use there service in PHP

https://www.ip2location.com/developers/php

I am not a full time coder any example on how to may be try will be very helpful.

**Error on cell Phone data**

Thank you for your advise @nmr, I found quite a bit of bugs on other plugins so I decided to fix them to see if it would make ip2location work but it didn't.

**Wifi / ethernet Connection: (This works great)**

```
2018-08-31 17:39:53 Lookup by BIN database.
2018-08-31 17:39:53 Geolocation result for [66.219.198.137] found: Array
(
    [ipNumber] => 1121699465
    [ipVersion] => 4
    [ipAddress] => 66.219.198.137
    [countryName] => United States
    [countryCode] => US
    [cityName] => Lehi
    [regionName] => Utah
)
```

**Cell Phone LTE Data Connection: (This Dosen't work )**

```
2018-08-31 17:40:04 Lookup by BIN database.
2018-08-31 17:40:31 Lookup by BIN database.
2018-08-31 17:40:31 Geolocation result for [127.0.0.1] found: Array
(
    [ipNumber] => 2130706433
    [ipVersion] => 4
    [ipAddress] => 127.0.0.1
    [countryName] => -
    [countryCode] => -
    [cityName] => -
    [regionName] => -
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using ["IP2Location Tag Wordpress Plugin"](https://www.ip2location.com/tutorials/wordpress-ip2location-tag).

In main file of IP2Location plugin, the class instance is created and assigned to the variable.

> $ip2location_tags = new IP2LocationTags();

To use the plugin in theme, just use the global variable `$ip2location_tags`. 
Remember to make sure that the class `IP2LocationTags` exists first and use `global` keyword.

```
if (class_exists('IP2LocationTags')) {
    global $ip2location_tags;
    $location = $ip2location_tags->get_location('IP_ADDRESS');
}
```

The plugin sets the IP address in this way (in `parse_content` method):

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && filter_var($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE)) {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
```

Keys in the location data table:

> ipAddress,
>   countryCode,
>   countryName,
>   regionName,
>   cityName,
>   latitude,
>   longitude,
>   isp,
>   domainName,
>   zipCode,
>   timeZone,
>   netSpeed,
>   iddCode,
>   areaCode,
>   weatherStationCode,
>   weatherStationName,
>   mcc,
>   mnc,
>   mobileCarrierName,
>   elevation,
>   usageType,

---

In `functions.php` file add function:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'ip2loc_get_region' ) ) {
    function ip2loc_get_region() {
        global $ip2location_tags;

        if ( !class_exists('IP2LocationTags') )
            return '';

        $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && filter_var($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE)) {
            $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }

        $location = $ip2location_tags->get_location($ip_address);
        if ( !$location )
            return '';

        return $location['regionName'];
    }
}
```

File `header.php`:

```
<?php

$def_header_text = esc_html__( 'This is Header Media Text.', 'cleanportfolio' );

if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
    $def_header_text .= '&nbsp;' . esc_html__( 'Edit this from Appearance - Customize - Header Media - Header Media Text.', 'cleanportfolio' );
}

$header_media_text = get_theme_mod( 'cleanportfolio_header_media_text', $def_header_text );

if ( is_front_page() && ( has_custom_header() || '' !== $header_media_text ) ) : ?>

    <?php // text to display
    $region_name = " " . ip2loc_get_region(); ?>

    <div class="custom-header">
        <?php
        if ( has_custom_header() ) : ?>
            <div class="custom-header-media">
                <?php the_custom_header_markup(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="custom-header-content sections header-media-section">

        <?php if ( '' !== $header_media_text ) : ?>
            <h2 class="section-title"><?php echo esc_html( $header_media_text ) . esc_html($region_name); ?></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
        <?php if ( ! has_custom_header() ) : ?>
            <div class="square"><?php echo cleanportfolio_get_svg( array(
                'icon' => 'square',
            ) ); ?><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Square', 'cleanportfolio' ); ?></span></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- .custom-header -->
```

Comment: Thank You so much this worked. You are very thorough. only one thing which was probably a typo . esc_html(region_name) is missing $ infront of region_name.

Comment: Hi @nmr its a long shot but i wanted to see if you know the answer to this.
I added the ip2location how you had instructed and it works flawlessly but when I open the site from an ipv6 address (Using cell phone data usually that's Ipv6) the site is blank. Do you know of an apparent reason you can think of why?
 https://newprelaunch.centsai.com/buyers-guides/credit-repair/

Comment: Try enable debug and paste error message. Add or uncomment in `wp-config.php` `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true )`, `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true )`. This will log errors to `/wp-content/debug.log` and display on page. If you also add `define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false )` errors will be only in log file.  See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#Example_wp-config.php_for_Debugging).  @DebanjanGhosh

Comment: Thank you for your advise, I found quite a bit of bugs on other plugins so I decided to fix them to see if it would make ip2location work but it didn't.

Comment: I added the debug file as an edit on my original post. @nmr

Comment: `Geolocation result for [127.0.0.1]`, it's loopback address. Sorry, i can't help you with this. I just do not know. @DebanjanGhosh

Comment: not a problem you have already helped me a lot. Thank you so much for taking the time.